# Sails.js ORM create method fails with `E_INVALID_RECORD`

Tags: sails.js

my sails.js app is configured to use sails-disk.

I am trying to create a document, but it keeps failing with `E_INVALID_RECORD` and the message is, `Failed process the values set for the record`.

Here's my `Reservation` model:

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'reservations',
    attributes: {
        person: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: 'number',
            required: true
        },
        slot: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        partner: {
            model: 'user',
            required: true
        }
    },
};
```

and here's how I am using it

```
const createdBooking = await Reservation.create(doc).fetch();
```

What could be the possible reasons for this?

**Edit: 1** here's the doc object

```
{
  date: 1523089876,
  slot: "3:01 PM",
  person: "Ayush Bahuguna",
  partner: 1
}
```

**Edit: 2** I should provide some clarification. I have written a `class` to parse the request body, here `doc` is an instantiated object of that class.

I tried passing directly `req.body` to the `create` method, and it worked, but it doesn't work with an instantiated object.

Here's my class:

```
class BookingRequest {
    constructor({person, date, slot, partner}){
        this.person = person;
        this.date = date;
        this.slot = slot;
        this.partner = partner;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:** So, I tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc))` and this time it worked. This is really bizarre.

Comment: Could you show the `doc` object you're passing as an argument ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi, Hi, I have added the doc object.

Comment: @HamzaFatmi I have added an important piece of information. Kindly, check.

Comment: why are you using a new class to pass the `req.body` to `model.create` method ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi to maintain the sanctity of the data received from the client, but how does that even matter, in the end I am still passing an object